# How to style a reactjs table inside APP.js file

Tags: reactjs, styles, inline-styles

I have this question, how do you style a react project table inside App.js? I prefer something which I could add directly to the file App.js, since this is a small application practice, no need to link to external .css.

```
const StatisticLine =(props) => {
  
  return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{props.text}</td>
          <td>{props.value}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
  </div>
)
}
```

[style should be something like this:](https://fullstackopen.com/static/a74acccc17aafb02b3801ffa1fcc0fdc/5a190/16e.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can style them by giving inline styles. Like I have styled the 1st  element below.

```
    const StatisticLine =(props) => {
  
  return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style={{fontSize: '20px', fontFamily: 'cursive', color: 'red' }}>{props.text}</td>
          <td>{props.value}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
  </div>
)
}
```